# Xcode 9.2 Shell Script Invocation Error

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, swift4, xcode9.2

I am facing `Shell Script Invocation Error` only when I am trying to *Archive* my project. But my project was running good in *Simulator* and in *Real Device*. How to solve this issue? I am using Xcode 9.2 in MacOS High Sierra.

Comment: What's the error that shows up in the build log?

Answer (score 0):

In Build Phase:

> Unchecked "Run script only when installing" if its checked.

And in Pods

> Update your pods dependencies to the latest version.

I hope this will help.